# Jquery question: How can I break up a multi-part form so that only one fieldset is visible at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, webforms

I have a firm grasp on XHTML & CSS, but PHP & Javascript look like magic to me.

I'm building a discussion site using the PHP-based [Textpattern CMS](http://textpattern.com). When users are logged in, they can use a public-side form to add a new discussion topic. There are a lot of input fields, grouped by the HTML `fieldset` element within a single `form` element that adds a new row to a specific database table. What I want to do is **show only one fieldset at a time**, inserting *previous* and *next* links that will allow people to **navigate between fieldsets**.

Textpattern comes bundled with jquery, and I found a [jquery plugin that describes this functionality](http://blog.vokle.com/index.php/2008/08/22/babysteps/). But I can't get it to work.

Here's what I have in my document `head`:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    fieldset {display: none;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://site.url/scripts/jquery.babysteps-0.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $('#step1').bindStep('#step2');
    $('#step2').bindStep('#step3');

    $('#step1').show();
</script>
```

My form is something like this:

```
<fieldset id="step1">
    <legend>Step 1 Fields</legend>
    <!-- fields -->
</fieldset>
<fieldset id="step2">
    <legend>Step 2 Fields</legend>
    <!-- fields -->
</fieldset>
<fieldset id="step3">
    <legend>Step 3 Fields</legend>
    <!-- fields -->
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" value="Post this Article!" />
```

The results are that the `style` declaration hides *every* `fieldset`, but the script doesn't show `step1` at all. I've double-checked all the file paths, and I've tried this using a link to my local jquery bundle instead of the Google version, but I get the same results.

I would be happy if I could get this working, but if there is another way to achieve this without the babysteps plugin, I'd be happy with that outcome as well.

Any guidance or concrete advice you can offer would be greatly appreciated! Step-by-step instructions or practical troubleshooting questions (Do you have your computer plugged in?) might also be helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Rich B as you can see here ppl take offense when you remove stuff like that :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not sure on that particular plugin, but with just jquery:

```
$(function(){

    $('#gotoStep2').click(function(){
        $('#step1').hide();
        $('#step2').show();
        return false;
    });

});
```

where you have

```
<input type="button" id="gotoStep2" value="next &raquo;"/>
```

inside step1

and your css:

```
#step2, #step3 //etc
{
    display: none;
}
```

im sure you can work out how to repeat this for all your steps :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! When you said "im sure you can work out how to repeat this for all your steps" I felt skeptical, but you were right! Your example gave me what I needed to get Next and Previous buttons working.

Comment: ;) told you. The best way to learn is to simply get stuck in. By the way the $(function(){ //code here }); bit makes sure the javascript is only run once the page has finished loading. You always want your jquery inside this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(function(){
    $("#step1").bindStep("#step2");
    $("#step2").bindStep("#step3");

    $("#step1").show();
  });
</script>
```

If that doesn't work, ditch the plugin. (Seriously, not even the demo on that page works.)

Comment: -1 for . (Seriously, not even the demo on that page works.) because it works

Comment: Indeed, I couldn't get the plugin working at all. Thanks you!

Comment: fmsf: Are we doing the same thing? I'm refering to the demo-link that leads to http://vokle.com/open-source/examples/babysteps/index.html . Using Chrome, that demo doesn't work. (When clicking the buttong, Step 1 is shown but with no next-button.)

Comment: I get the same results as svinto in Safari.

Comment: The new safari seems to have some issues with jquery, ive noticed that